# Cómo añadir color a una consulta en vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Es posible agregar color a una consulta en vue js?, es decir, cuando consulto un Select, o un Input, estos pueden tener 4 posibles respuestas, Vacío = Azul, Inminente = Rojo, Probable = Amarillo y Posible= Verde, cómo podría agregar este color si cumple la condición de consulta?, cabe decir que son muchisismas consultas y solo cambia de color si muevo el select, pero por defecto es azul siempre, sin importar la consulta.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade por favor lo que llevas hecho y las dudas específicas

Answer (score 2):

Dependiendo de la opción seleccionada en el `SELECT`, la clase del div cambiara, y junto a la clase el color.

Por favor da click en **ejecutar** para ver el resultado.

```js
var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    id: null,
    opciones: [
      { id: null, nombre: 'Vacio' },
      { id: 1, nombre: 'Inminente' },
      { id: 2, nombre: 'Probable' },
      { id: 3, nombre: 'Posible' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      console.log(this.id);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.azul{
  background-color: #00f;
}

.rojo{
  background-color: #f00;
}

.amarillo{
  background-color: #ff0;
}

.verde{
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select @change="onChange()" v-model="id">
    <option v-for="opcion in opciones" v-bind:value="opcion.id">
    {{ opcion.nombre }}
  </option>
  </select>

  <div v-bind:class="
  {
    'azul': id == null,
    'rojo': id == 1,
    'amarillo': id == 2,
    'verde': id == 3
  }">
    <p>Hola mundo</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Cómo te había comentado, es una consulta, ya me funciona que cambie de color apenas esté seleccionando una opción, ahora, cuando consulta el valor desde firestore, ese valor por ejemplo: Inmimente, debería ser Rojo por defecto, y no azul como se muestra en la imagen...

Comment: @RafaelGaitan ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que no soy muy conocido del lenguaje, apenas he hecho y leido la documentación, pero no dice nada alli, el php lo hice, pero pues, era algo como: `if(c_amenaza_natural.terremoto == 'Probable'){ style="background-color: #f00"}` y listo, pero en vue js, la verdad es que no me las apaño, o no encuentro nada, y el color se mantiene si hago el registro y al editar no he recargado la página, pero esa no es la idea.